# regex does not match if string contains spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using regex `js\w*=\"[^\"]+\"` to match and replace tags in HTML that begin with `js` like  `jsname="name" jscontroller="somecontroller"` etc.

Problem is, if there are spaces before and after the `=` sign it matches nothing. How can this be solved?

This matches fine `jsname="name" jscontroller="somecontroller"`

This does not match but should: `jsname = "name" jscontroller   =  "somecontroller"`

Can you help?

Comment: Add `\h*` before and after the equal sign to match for any number of horizontal spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `js\w*\s*=\s*\"[^\"]+\"`

Comment: Ok. This works. I was trying `js\w\s*=\"[^\"]+\"`

Comment: Happy to hear that. That would be nice to mark this as correct answer.